# USe NSCoding To Create User Editable Plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, nscoding

I'm trying to create a user editable plist where the user can store a custom created workout routine including strings referenced from another data.plist in the app bundle.

I'm assuming NSCoding is the best way to go about this.  So far I have the interface setup as a nav bar and table view.

I want it to be blank be default and the user has to press the "+" that is in the top right of the nav bar.  Then he could enter a name for an entry in an array, for example chest day, or bicep day.  And within that array, will be a dictionary or another array of strings of the particular exercises for that day, for example bench press, or bicep curl.

This plist needs to be editable so it will be going in the users document folder and not in the app bundle.

Example:

Top array consists of Chest Day, Back Day, Leg Day.  Within Chest Day dictionary, include bench press, chest pull, pushup, etc.

Update:

Adding this method to search for routine file;

```
    -(void)loadData
{
    if(YES)
    {
        NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* routineFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"routine.plist"];
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:routineFile];
    }
    else
    {
        //load file
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry Quixoto.  My question is where would I start with trying to implement this editable plist? I know how to read from plist into tables but not how to make an editable plist starting from one with no entries

Comment: I think part of the difficulty is figuring out just what you mean by "editable plist." Any .plist file is editable, assuming you have the proper read/write permissions and ownership. It's worth keeping in mind, though, that the plist is just a *storage* format - what you'll be working with in your app, while editing the data, is NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSString objects, not a plist.

Comment: Thanks Sherm.  Yeah I understand that.  what I need is for the user to be able to edit the content in the plist.  So users can rearrange items in the dictionary, or rearrange dictionaries within the root array.  I don't think this should be hard to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSCoding is the protocol used by NSArchiver, NSKeyedArchiver, etc., not for serializing an array into a property list.

Forget about the idea that the user is going to edit a property list. The user is going to edit data in your app -- the fact that it's stored as a property list is just an implementation detail. When your app starts, you read the data stored in the data file. The user edits it, looks at it, whatever. At some point later, perhaps after each edit, perhaps just before the app quits, you write the data back out to the file. Since it's a property list, don't worry about updating the file; you already have all the data, so write a whole new property list and then use that file to replace the old one.

Perhaps I'm wrong and you really do intend for the user to edit the property list by hand, with a text editor. This would be a mistake. It's great the property lists are human readable, but asking your users to edit your raw data files by hand is a strong indication that your app is broken. The whole purpose of your app is to keep track of this information for the user; if they wanted to use a text editor to manage it, they wouldn't need your app. So, with that said, I hope I'm not wrong. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Cabel, yeah know I understand the difference between the data stored in the plist and the plist itself.  And you're right, I was not explaining correctly - I DON't want the user to edit the plist, just the data that is stored in it.  How would I begin this process though?  I can't seem to find out where to begin

Comment: Begin what process? You seem to have a pretty clear idea of the way you want to structure your data. When the app starts up, you look for your data file. If you find one, you read it. If you don't find one, you create an empty mutable array so that the user can start adding items. Later, after the app does its thing for a while, the array will hopefully not be empty, so you'll serialize it as Sherm Pendley described. More info [here](http://tinyurl.com/4hmt9fs).

Comment: Thanks Caleb.  I'm editing my original post with a new method I am implementing to check whether file exists or needs to be crated or to load the file if it exists.  Am I on the right track? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, but you can also just use +arrayWithContentsOfFile: as @Sherm Pendley suggested. You'll get nil back if the file can't be opened or read into an array.

Comment: Ok thanks Caleb, I read through the link but still confused as to exactly where to start.  I need to first check whether or not there is data in the cells, so how can I use `+arrayWithContentsOfFile:` to do that?

Comment: `NSArray *myData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"mydata"]; if (myData == nil) { myData = [NSMutableArray array]; }` Now you have the array that you'll use to populate your table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd use NSCoding for this - if all you're working with is standard plist objects like NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSString, the top array's -writeToFile:atomically: method is an easy way to do the job.

Comment: OK, I guess I thought NSCoding was the way to do this.  I think I didn't sate my question very clear.  Where would I start with trying to implement this editable plist?  I know how to read from plist into tables but not how to make an editable plist starting from one with no entries.

Comment: NSArray's -writeToFile:atomically: creates a file in plist format - that's where you start, and that's where you finish. There is no step two. :-)

Comment: Similarly, +arrayWithContentsOfFile: will read the file back in.